# Grab current URLCodeception and printing it

Tags: unit-testing, testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

I've been trying to grab the current root link with the function GrabFromCurrentUrl. I cant assert why it's not doing what I've intended it to do.

```
$uri = $I->grabFromCurrentUrl();
$I->seeMyVar($uri);`
```

Reference: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#grabfromcurrenturl

Comment: What result do you get? It only works after opening some page in the test.

Comment: It says that the variable is not defined.

Comment: Please run codeception with `-vvv` parameter and provide a complete error message and a stacktrace.